# $.get function not running in Chrome but working in IE and FireFox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm working on a site that uses php POST to upload files to a server and i'm trying to add a progress bar to the uploads.
I followed this guide:

http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/

It works great in ie and firefox. But the progressbar never updates in chrome.

This function gets called with a timeout of "500".

```
function updateProgress(id) {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    // Make a GET request to the server
    // Pass our upload identifier as a parameter
    // Also pass current time to prevent caching
    $.get('progressbar.php', { uid: id, t: time }, function (data) {
        // Get the output as an integer
        var progress = parseInt(data, 10);
        if (progress < 100 || !started) {
            var div = document.getElementById('statusfield');
            div.innerHTML = progress + '%';
            // Determine if upload has started
            started = progress < 100;

            // If we aren't done or started, update again
            updateProgress(id);
        }
        if (progress > 99) {
            var div = document.getElementById('statusfield');
            div.innerHTML = 'Komprimerar fil...';
        }
        // Update the progress bar percentage
        // But only if we have started
        started && pbar.progressbar('value', progress);
    });
}
```

This function calls the .php file "progressbar.php" which passes the upload progress back as a percentage number.

progressbar.php:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {
        // Fetch the upload progress data
        $status = uploadprogress_get_info($_GET['uid']);
        if ($status) {
            // Calculate the current percentage
            echo round($status['bytes_uploaded']/$status['bytes_total']*100);
        }
        else {
            // If there is no data, assume it's done
            echo 100;
        } 
    }
?>
```

I have tested the code in chrome and the function "updateProgress" gets called. But it never gets past the:

```
$.get('progressbar.php', { uid: id, t: time }, function
```

Does anyone have any clue on what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see information passing in the console?

Answer (score 1):

In chrome go to dev tools (Options -> Tools -> Developer tools) and look at the network panel. Once the $.get method is called you will see your request and the result - you can see if it fails (for example if a 404 happens) so maybe chrome doesn't set the address as it should or if the sent data / return data isn't ok.

Comment: sorry, it was intended to be a comment :)